# evitar descargar en href=

Tags: html, c#, css, razor

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente problema

`<li class="list-items"><a href="../MascotaFeliz.App.Frontend/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" target="_blank" class="botones">Admin</a>`

al dar click a Admin necesito que se vaya a la pagina razor pero en ves de irse a ella se descarga el código html. me gastaría saber que etiqueta me puede enviar a la pagina deseada en vez de descargarla

Gracias

Comment: La descarga porque estas haciendo referencia a un archivo fisico, el servidor piensa que quieres a archivo, necesitas poner una url valida que sea llamada por medio de un metodo en un controlador. Como cuando mandas llamar en un href a /Home/Index etc

Answer (score 0):

No estás redireccionando de la forma correcta, estas usando razor, asi que toda vista debe ser mostrada a traves de un controlador. Este ejemplo te servirá `<a href="@Url.Action("Categorias", "Main")">` donde Main es el controlador MainController, y Categorias es el ActionResult que devuelve la vista.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias si me funcionó :)

Comment: Recuerda marcar como la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos